# NavigationController title doesn't appear swift/storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard

This is my story board. I want to set the ttitle for this `FrontViewController` So I did this in my `FrontViewController`

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(true)
    self.navigationController!.navigationBar.topItem!.title = "Home";
}
```

I have also tried:

```
self.title="Home"
self.navigationItem.title = "Home"
```

But it doesn't set any title. Why is that? Pleasehelp me.
Thanks

**This is my story board**
[image]

Comment: delete and regenerate the navigation congtroller once

Answer (score 0):

USe this code it works for you

```
override func viewDidLoad() 
{
    self.title="your title"
```

Or

```
 self.navigationItem.title = "YourTitle"
```

Comment: self.navigationItem.title = "home"

Comment: :( still same. no luck

Comment: if it is not working you may use an image with that title on that place

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
self.navigationItem.title = "Home"
```

If your `ViewController` is inside `UINavigationController` then write this line in `viewDidLoad()` method of your `ViewController`.

Additionally if it doesn't work, try to add on button inside `Navigation Item` and give button title, this must work.

Comment: In given image, which one should have title "Home"?

Comment: Front View Controller

Comment: Could you explain how your answer addresses the problem(s) from the question? Code-only answers are not very useful, especially for further readers that stumble upon this post. Thanks!

Comment: @Cristik, Sure, this answer point exact what the problem is.
If you want to show title of your view controller which is inside UINavigationController, your can use that code.
What do you think is not useful?

Comment: @NitinGohel , I thought this may help, so posted as answer.

Comment: @ZaidPathan you should update your answers with more details, otherwise it's likely it will get deleted. As I previously said, code-only answers don't provide much value.

Comment: @Cristik, that make sense, I will surely do that.

Comment: @user1960169 Can you try additional answer I've attached?